# Is it possible to remove Remote Login as an option from System Preferences altogether?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, remote-desktop, login, screen-sharing

*Somebody in my family has recently been trying to spy on my computer, and I was trying to buy them a surprise gift...  I keep turning off Remote Login, but they turn it on while I'm not paying attention.*

*At first it was Screen Sharing, and now Remote Login, and I'm fairly sure they will stop at nothing!*

I disabled Remote Login as best I could (with Firewall), but **was wondering if there were some way to use Terminal to remove the option altogether.**  Removing Screen Sharing would be great too.

Thanks for your help.

Side note, **how can I tell when they are remotely connected to my computer?**  Screen sharing has the symbol in the menu bar, but what does Remote Login do?

Comment: remote login lets them connect via SSH, though some third party screen sharing/viewing applications use it too I believe

Comment: As to finding out weather they are connecting using remote login (and to block all incoming connections from them), you can use a tool like little snitch